# Vue3 and cypress: how to test router.push events?

Tags: cypress, vuejs3, vue-router

I am using vue3 composition API, vue-router, and cypress, and when I call:

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="sidebar-customers"]').click()
```

the element receives the click event and `router.push(path: '/customers')` is called, and everything works fine in my app. However, in cypress, the screen does not change to follow the path to which the router is pointing.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried to call `cypress.visit('/customer');` after your click on the customers sidebar?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I believe it would cause the page to refresh.  I had a prior bug that specifically had to do with `router.push` (as opposed to `router.go`), and so I'm trying to make a test that would prevent that bug from reoccurring.

Comment: Hi @Julie, did you manage to get Cypress to work with Vue Router? I am also running into problems with using /visit as it refreshes the page.

Comment: @Simon unfotunately not 